# Cloudbees - build pending and "waiting for next available executor" forever

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I'm trying to run a build on CloudBees, but can't do it. Build is still "pending—Waiting for next available executor" for hours. I entered node configuration (there is only one node - master) and tried to enter different numbers as number of executors, but still can't run the build.

What might I be missing?

Comment: You shouldn't modify the nodes section. Masters and executors are automatically configured by CloudBees. Did you try restart the build? Maybe it was just a momentary issue.

Comment: Maybe it was. I checked now and it passed. But it was pending for more than 12 hours.